# Editing different meshes together -- Bezier curve and Circle

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, knife-tool

I've had 100% success finding answers to questions on this site, though, I've finally become stalled on one problem in which I don't even know how to phrase into a search.

I can't seem to edit both meshes at the same time. The first mesh started from a 'CIRCLE' and the second mesh started from a 'BEZIER CURVE' which I converted to mesh via ALT+C --> Mesh from Curve.

I'm trying to knife the intersection and delete the inner faces but I cannot get both of the objects into edit mode (mesh) at the same time? I notice both are on different scenes - "BezierCurve" and "Circle", which I feel has something to do with the problem?

Here are two pictures showing the two different meshes in edit mode while the other one remains in object mode. Any feedback is greatly appreciated!
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. You can **never** enter edit mode in two objects at the same time, this is a fundamental part of Blenders design philosophy
2. If you want to edit two meshes at the same time join them together with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Have in mind that this may have undesirable effects, and will mess with modifiers.
3. Knife project doesn't require entering edit mode in two objects at the same time, only the object to be cut. You may be confusing it object mode *Boolean* operations
4. Knife project will not work well for what you are trying to achieve. It only works when the "knife" object is a flat shape or fundamentally bi-dimentional

You may want to use the *Boolean* modifier or edit mode Boolean Operations instead. The former requires two objects, but no edit mode, the later requires you yo join both objects.

Have in mind that both Knife Project and Boolean operations are discourage modelling tools. [Booleans are very prone to errors](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=boolean), and both will produce low quality meshes, with bad topology, duplicate geometry, artifacts, hard to texture and bad for animation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Duarte. I used Ctrl+J in Object Mode to join them and was able to edit the meshes together in Edit mode. I used Ctrl+F in Edit Mode --> 'Intersect (Knife)' to create the intersection points and then was able to delete the inner faces on both objects:
[image]