# process of combining 2 meshes into one not in object mode but in edit mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I made a mistake of creating another mesh in edit mode so when I use ctrl + J to combine mesh it doesn't work. What would be a good way to combine 2 meshes together in edit mode since they are already considered as one mesh object? As you can see I would like to merge both the cone and the cylinder together into one single mesh. The cylinder is just a extrusion of the ball object. For now I'm going to re-add the cone in object mode then ctrl + j to merge.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76343/editing-different-meshes-together-bezier-curve-and-circle/76347#76347 also relevant https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51318/how-to-really-make-it-only-one-object/51322#51322

Comment: " re-add the cone in object mode then ctrl + j to merge." you will get essentially the same as what is shown on the screenshot.

Comment: @Mr Zak does that mean I have over lapping polygon right now? Because this is what I made after redoing it in object mode. [Picture of what I made](http://http://i.imgur.com/bsmsj6S.png)

Comment: Not necessarily. What I wanted to tell is that by Ctrl+J you only join 2 objects (consisting of 1 or more meshes) into 1 object consisting of multiple meshes. It won't merge any geometry, it all will continue being the same as it was before joining. It's hard to tell if you have any bad geometry there; try removing doubles and then in Vertex mode without any selected run Ctrl+Alt+Shift+M, if it selects anything then yep you have something inproper (even if nothing selected though it doesn't mean nothing is bad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do? Deleting the cone, adding it in object mode, and then using ctrl + j just gets you back to where you started. Its the same as adding it in edit mode.

Assuming you want to join them to one flowing mesh.

1. Select the edge loops with <kbd>alt</kbd> + rightclick
2. Search in the space search menu for bridge edge loops
3. Select it from the search

Before:
[image: Before]

After:[image: After]

Comment: [Here is what I made in object mode](http://i.imgur.com/bsmsj6S.png) Pretty much just to connect the cone and the cylinder. If Ctrl + J is just as same as what I did in edit mode my next question would be are there overlapping polygons withing the newly merged object right now? Because my cylinder stabs into the cone a little bit to show no gaps.

Comment: @lukechen Yes there are overlaps. Its not magically connecting two meshes. It just makes Blender treat two disconnected but overlapping meshes as one object. You should watch a few modeling tutorials to get a feel for it. To see the overlap go to edit mode with tab and push "z" for wire frame.

Comment: @ Aoradon thanks, I have been watching tutorials and I'm currently in the experimenting phase.